# How do I call Json wih angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I am trying to fix my response function.

I think the problem lies in my controller.js, but I could be very wrong:

```
angular
    .module('OrganisatieApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('organisatieController', function ($scope, organisatieAPIservice) {
        $scope.organisatieList = [];
        organisatieAPIservice.getOrganisaties().success(function (response) {
            //Assign response in Callback
            $scope.organisatieList = response(); // as you can see here there needs something to be added but i really dont know what it could be.
        });
    });

$scope.organisatieList = response(what is in here?);
```

Normally, it would be something like this:

```
response.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
```

But I have no idea what is happening in that line.

This is my *app.js*

```
angular
    .module('OrganisatieApp', [
        'OrganisatieApp.controllers',
        'OrganisatieApp.services'
    ]);
```

And this my *services.js*:

```
angular
    .module('OrganisatieApp.services', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('organisatieAPIservice', function ($resource) {
        var organisatieAPIservice = [];
        organisatieAPIservice.getOrganisaties = function () {
            return $http({
                method: 'JSONP',
                url: 'http://jbossews-themaopdracht78.rhcloud.com/rest/json/org/Organisaties'
            });
        }
        return organisatieAPIservice;
    });
```

This is my html div:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Organisatie naam</th>
                <th>Organisatie plaats</th>
                <th>Organisatie Curriculum</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="organisatie in organisatieList">
                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                <td>
                    <img src="/img/logos/{{organisatie.Organisatie.logo}}.png" />
                    {{organisatie.Organisatie.orgNaam}}&nbsp;{{organisatie.Organisatie.orgVolledig}}
                </td>
                <td>{{organisatie.Constructors[0].provincie}}</td>
                <td>{{organisatie.curriculum}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong and why cant I get data in my table?

Comment: in services.js you're injecting `ngResource`, but you're using `$http` instead.

Comment: Seems like that url does not support jsonp, it returns a json instead of the one with padding, also when using jsonp you would nee to [provide callback as JSON_CALLBACK](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp).

Comment: The ngResource was the problem. But now i have to make it work for json since it gives that back. This may be a stupid question but: how do i make it support jsonp or how can i make json work for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: JSON work for you ? Can you elaborate